# How to get the IEEE 754 binary representation of a float in C#

Tags: c#, binary, floating-point, ieee-754

I have some single and double precision floats that I want to write to and read from a byte[]. Is there anything in .Net I can use to convert them to and from their 32 and 64 bit IEEE 754 representations?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

.NET Single and Double are already in IEEE-754 format.  You can use [BitConverter.ToSingle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.tosingle?view=net-5.0) and [ToDouble()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.todouble?view=net-5.0) to convert byte[] to floating point, [GetBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes?view=net-5.0) to go the other way around.

Comment: How can We do this without using GetBytes(). i mean using forloops

Answer (score 9):

Update for current .NET/C# using spans:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    Span<byte> data = stackalloc byte[20];
    GetBytes(0, data, 0);
    GetBytes(123.45F, data, 4);
    GetBytes(123.45D, data, 8);
}

static unsafe void GetBytes(float value, Span<byte> buffer, int offset)
    => MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, float>(buffer.Slice(offset))[0] = value;
static unsafe void GetBytes(double value, Span<byte> buffer, int offset)
    => MemoryMarshal.Cast<byte, double>(buffer.Slice(offset))[0] = value;
```

---

If you don't want to allocate new arrays all the time (which is what `GetBytes` does), you can use `unsafe` code to write to a buffer directly:

```
static void Main()
{
    byte[] data = new byte[20];
    GetBytes(0, data, 0);
    GetBytes(123.45F, data, 4);
    GetBytes(123.45D, data, 8);
}

static unsafe void GetBytes(float value, byte[] buffer, int offset)
{
    fixed (byte* ptr = &buffer[offset])
    {
        float* typed = (float*)ptr;
        *typed = value;
    }
}
static unsafe void GetBytes(double value, byte[] buffer, int offset)
{
    fixed (byte* ptr = &buffer[offset])
    {
        double* typed = (double*)ptr;
        *typed = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the implications for doing it this way compared to creating an array? I'm interested in what happens in memory and what the GC does etc.

Comment: @Backwards_Dave simply: one allocates an array, one doesn't! what GC does will depend entirely upon when that array is unreachable, but: it will need to be collected at some point. Note that in current .NET/C#, you could use a `Span<byte>` API here, and do the entire thing without any `unsafe` and without any array allocations *at all* (using a `stackalloc` span) - see edit