# c# and floating point inaccuracies

Tags: c#, floating-point, ieee-754

I am trying to understand floating point inaccuracies and how to handle them in c#.

I have looked at [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples) which gives some good answers, but I want to understand it specifically to c#.

Using decimal '8.8', how would I convert this to a binary representation and then back to decimal so that that that value changes to '8.8000000000000007'?

I have tried using suggestions from [How to get the IEEE 754 binary representation of a float in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249414/how-to-get-the-ieee-754-binary-representation-of-a-float-in-c-sharp) without luck.

Comment: The number you are expecting is outside of the range of a floating point. Outside of that it is trivial to convert 8.8 to a byte array and back to a float.  What exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the thing, though: 8.8000000000000007 can't be exactly represented in `double`, either. The closest value is 8.800000000000000710542735760100185871124267578125 (which I got from Jon Skeet's [DoubleConverter](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs)). You could then use `Decimal.Parse` on that string to get a decimal value of 8.80000000000000071054273576.

```
decimal d = 8.8M;
double dbl = (double)d;
string s = DoubleConverter.ToExactString(dbl);
decimal dnew = decimal.Parse(s);
```

Comment: 11 years later, the link to the DoubleConverter was no longer working. If anyone needs it, I found it here: http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs

Answer (score 0):

You can compare some different doubles like this:

```
double a = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 156, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 33, 64, }, 0);
double b = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 155, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 33, 64, }, 0);
double c = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 154, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 33, 64, }, 0);
double d = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 33, 64, }, 0);
double e = BitConverter.ToDouble(new byte[] { 152, 153, 153, 153, 153, 153, 33, 64, }, 0);
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("R"));
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("R"));
Console.WriteLine(c.ToString("R"));
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("R"));
Console.WriteLine(e.ToString("R"));
```

Using the [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) `"R"` shows extra digits but only if necessary to distinguish between other representable `System.Double`.

Addition ([explanation of the bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)): `64` and `33` give the sign, magnitude and first (most) significant bits of the number `8.8`. Since `8.8` is a fraction with a small denominator (the 5 in 44/5), it is not surprising that the rest of the bits repeat over and over with a short period. To get the exact `8.8`, the 153s would have to continue forever. But there's only room for eight bytes in a `double`. Therefore we need to round. Rounding to `154` gives the closest value because the next "term" (`153`) is closer to `256` than to `0`. Therefore `c` is the most precise representation possible.

When you look through the output of the above code, you see that `c` is just output as `8.8` even when we used the `"R"` format string. But you know that `c` is halfway between `b` and `d` (and also halfway between `a` and `e`), and from that you can easily estimate that the "true" decimal value most be very near `8.8000000000000007`.